# Recurring Explorer error that I cannot trace

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'd consider myself a fairly advanced home user, even daring to call myself a superuser but I've recently experienced a recurring error dialog that I cannot trace that is driving me mad.

My workstation is a Windows 10 64Bit Version 1809 (Build 17763.316) and I get the recurring dialog:

["This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgUmp.png)

What's weird is that there is no corresponding log in the event viewer under the "Application" or the "System" event logs. Is there anything I can do to trace this issue further?

Applications running at the time of error:

- Visual Studio 2015
- SQL Server Management Studio
- Google Chrome (only my web app is open and there's nothing that calls for an app to open)
- Eset NOD32 Antivirus (12.1.31.0)
- Sticky Notes

Is there a way to enable advanced debugging or trace what process is trying to open a file? There are no scheduled tasks that would suggest they're the cause of this issue either..

---

Comment: Can you open any EXE file after a clean reboot?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yes everything appears to be fine (applications etc) except for the dialog that pops up intermittently